# Can IE manipulate XML using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, dom

**What I am not trying to do:**

- Simply "read" XML in IE using jQuery. Been there, done that. Works for the most part.
- Load XML via AJAX. This is a legacy system using XML in a hidden field (oh yah, baby!) between postbacks to store a wizard data structure. Rewriting it would suck.

**What I am trying to do:**

- *Manipulate* the XML document using jQuery in IE
- Use the same code across all browsers, using the native jQuery functionality

**What I would be okay with:**

- Overriding/overloading the same jquery methods to get them to work in IE when manipulating the XML DOM.

It just doesn't work and I feel like it just isn't possible in a 100% cross browser way using plain old jQuery methods.

Case in point:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IE Sucks</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var xml =
            '<Browsers>' +
                '<CoolBrowsers>' +
                    '<Browser name="Opera"></Browser>' +
                    '<Browser name="Chrome"></Browser>' +
                    '<Browser name="Firefox"></Browser>' +
                '</CoolBrowsers>' +
                '<BadBrowsers>' +
                    '<Browser name="IE6"></Browser>' +
                '</BadBrowsers>' +
            '</Browsers>';

        $(function () {

            $("#xml").text(xml);

            var uncoolBrowser = $("<Browser />").attr("name", "IE7");

            // In 1.5, using this...
            var $xml = $($.parseXML(xml));

            // Nope. Works everywhere else, though!
            // var $xml = $(xml);     


            // Throws a "Type mismatch"
            // Works everywhere except IE
            // This is case sensitive (??? WTF ???)
            // Lowercase "badbrowsers" nothing happens
            // Uppercase "BADBROWSERS" nothing happens
            // Best part? $xml.find("BadBrowsers").length === 1
            $xml.find("BadBrowsers").append(uncoolBrowser);

            // Only way to output XML in IE
            $("#result").text($xml[0].xml);

            // Fuggetaboutit
            // Technically, it does work in IE but not when using $.parseXML()
            // $("#result").text($("<div></div>").append($xml.clone()).html());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <pre id="xml"></pre>
    <pre id="result"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible? Can this simple scenario be done or has IE just forsaken us all? `$(xml).everything`, etc. works in FF, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

**Update**

**It is possible using voodoo magicks.**

I've [created a jQuery plugin](https://github.com/kamranayub/jQuery-XML-Helper) that takes care of reconciling the differences between different browser handling of XML. I also made an `.xml()` function based on similar code elsewhere, though mine fixes an IE-only issue. This works in all browsers, IE7 & IE8 for sure, can't test IE6.

I have posted this on my github. If anyone has suggestions or improvements, let me know. There are several things I've already run into but I have been fixing them as I run into them.

Comment: Theres's some caveats I've been working through. Since I am effectively tricking IE into treating it as an HTML document, it treats some tags and attributes differently, causing unexpected results. For the most part, I've hacked and slashed around them but it's complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a guess as I don't know offhand what .parseXml does but IE needs `createElement` for unknown node names. Can you try `document.createElement('BadBrowsers')` for every new node you are going to manipulate?

This is the case with HTML5 and that's why there are shiv scripts. You can try just taking this:

http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js

Copying it, append your new node names to `var z`, and then:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="file.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I still seem to get the Type Mismatch but I could be implementing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion pointed me in the right direction and I came up with a solution!

Comment: You should accept meder's answer and move your own to the end of your question. Just sayin'...

Comment: Actually it turned out his answer is incorrect, as there is much more that needs to happen with jQuery. Still, he did point me in the right direction.

Comment: @subkamran Actually the right way would have been to answer your own question (maybe even accept it), not to put the answer into the question.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, I get mixed responses about that. Some people dislike that, others say that's the "right way." It seems to me your suggestion is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Refer to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).